# Excel freezes when expanding group of rows with conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

**Issue:** Excel freezes when expanding group of rows which contain conditional formatting. I can save using `CTRL + S`, but worksheet functionality and toolbar buttons lock up.

**Working solution:** Deleting the conditional formatting, which consists of:

- Rule: `=AND($C7<>"",$C7<>0)`
- Applies to: `=$C$7:$AB$84`

**Excel version:** Excel 2016

**File Type:** .xlsb

**Background details:** Rows were initially grouped with a macro. VBA code which groups the rows:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(firstRow, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, 1)).Rows.Group
ws.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
```

`Screenupdating` is set to `True`. There are no other row groups. Beyond failure to expand the group, I have not come accross any other issues with the file.

How can I prevent this without deleting the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar bug with Excel 2013 (15.0.4569.1504) MSO (15.0.4719.1000) 32 Bit.

The bug could be reproduced as such :

- Expand a group so that the new rows will exceed the bottom of the 
  screen and force the screen to scroll up.
- Similarly, unhide rows
  in the same conditions.

I was able to find several other workaround :

- Change the height of the first row
- Remove "Heading" (from Ribbon View - Heading).
- Remove Those 3 options TOEGETHER (from option - advanced).

  - Show horizontal scroll bar
  - Show vertical scroll bar
  - Show sheet Tabs
- Change Screen zoom
- UnFreezing panel
- Delete ALL conditionnal formating
- Use another computer.

The following actions had no impacts :

- Groups are not involved, unhiding rows is the key :

  - reduce nesting group level => Freeze
  - Delete all groups and rebuild them => Freeze
- Other graphical components are not involved :

  - Delete comments => Freeze
  - Delete VBA components (buttons) => Freeze
  - Clean unused format (with XlStyleTool) => Freeze
  - Unmerge cells => Freeze
- One single conditional formatting leads to the problem  :

  - Delete some conditional formatting => Freeze
  - changing condition formulas => Freeze
  - changing option (stop if true) => Freeze
  - changing format => Freeze
  - Delete all conditional formatting, save file under another name and create one new conditional formatting => Freeze
- File format is not involved :

  - Saving the file to Excel 2003 format and use it in compatibility mode. => Freeze
  - Copy the sheet to another workbook. => Freeze
  - Using page Break view instead of normal. => Freeze
- Disable Hardware Acceleration => Freeze
- Disable Add-in => Freeze

My conclusion is that it is a graphical bug linked to my video driver in very specific conditions. I just increased the first row size which fixed the problem.

My graphical card and drivers are :

- AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series - BIOS Version 013.009.000.010
- Catalyst Version  15.7.1
- Windows 7 - 64 Bit - Sp1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one particular sheet. My workaround was set the same font for all the sheet (font and size)